# Forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) error even though I changed back to 23?

Tags: android, build.gradle

I get that I need to use SDK 23 and to my knowledge I am setting it to 23 yet it is still giving me the following error message in play store:

- It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M
  permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style
  permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from
  version 5 (target SDK 23) to version 6 (target SDK 22).
- **Version 5** is not served to any device configuration: all devices
  that might receive **version 5** would receive **version 6**.

In the past I DID try to change the SDK to 22 (after live version was 23). Since learning this is not allowed I am trying to revert back to 23. But after I change everything in my gradle back to 23 (picture below) it is still giving me the error message that I am not allowed to use 22. Is it possible that I am forgetting to change the 22 somewhere outside of the gradle? This is really frustrating. Here is a picture of my build.gradle:

[image]